# Why does VSCode insert irregular whitespace instead of normal whitespace?

Tags: visual-studio-code

when i'm writing my markdown, very often VSCode changes whitespace to something else, e.g., `# Example` -> `# Example`. It looks the same, but it's not whitespace (eslint says **no-irregular-whitespace** which is how I was able to spot it, but in MD this doesn't show).

```
> `#  Hello`.charCodeAt(0)
35
> `#  Hello`.charCodeAt(1)
160
> `#  Hello`.charCodeAt(2)
32
> `#  Hello`.charCodeAt(3)
72
```

It causes a lot of trouble occasionally. Why does it do that?

Comment: Do you use a modifier key to type `#`? On my keyboard it's Alt-3, and Alt-Space inserts a non-breaking space on macOS, so I often accidentally break Markdown headings (https://github.com/textbook/react-ts-fe/commit/d19d123521de8b6ed815fe8ec537d91d64445004).